# How to publish a react based component through npm without including react?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I have a simple component that requires react and mobx to use. When I build my library through webpack, it is including react and mobx and mobx-react in the bundle. However I would like to add them as a peer dependency and let the user of my module install the libraries.

Is this possible? My webpack config looks like this and it builds nicely into dist/build.js I just need to work out how to exclude the libraries.

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [ './index.js' ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./dist'),
        filename: 'build.js',
        library: 'myLibrary',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs'
    },  
    module: {
        rules: loaders
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            sourceMap: true,
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            }
        })
    ]
}
```

Comment: this is my build script that i used to output the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mark as "external" dependency in your package.json:

```
externals: { 'react': 'commonjs react' }
```

Here is a short but very useful article about publishing components on npm flawlessy:

https://medium.com/@BrodaNoel/how-to-create-a-react-component-and-publish-it-in-npm-668ad7d363ce

Comment: You'd also need to mark React as a `peerDependency` in `package.json` to stop it getting installed when you pull the component down from NPM.

Answer (score 1):

There is a distinction you need to make between building for development and testing of your lib, and what will be actually used by the consumer of your lib. They most likely wont need to be using a pre-built lib

Your webpack build is likely only for your own development purposes, in which case it is perfectly fine and necessary to have react and any other dependencies bundled in the build.

When a consumer comes to use your library via npm, your package should usually point them to the source code index.js, rather a built file, and their own build will trace the dependencies via the `require`/`import`s and bundle them up itself, in which case it would use their peer dependencies rather than your libs dependencies

It would only be necessary to pre-build distributions via your own webpack config if you are wanting to make builds for consumption directly via a script tag on the web, or taget UMD commonJS specifically. In that case you can have your webpack config declare react and friends as `externals` https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals

If it is only to be consumed by importing as a node module, it should be enough to add peer dependencies to your package for the modules you would like to be supplied by the consumer, and make sure the main file is referenced, so their own build knows where to import it from

```
"main": "./index.js", // source code entry (this is what consumer requires, at which point their build will trace deps to react etc)
"peerDependencies": {
  "react": "*",
  "mobx-react": "*" // or required min versions
}
```